# Pygame only recognizing one joystick in 2 joystick controller

Tags: python, pygame

I'm making code where I connect my bluetooth controller (PS4) and route it to certain commands with pygame, I want to use both joysticks but I apparently can only use one!

```py
import pygame

pygame.init()
pygame.joystick.init()

# List the available joystick devices
for i in range(pygame.joystick.get_count()):
    print(f"Joystick {i}: {pygame.joystick.Joystick(i).get_name()}")
```

It gives me this:

```
Joystick 0: PS4 Controller
```

Why can't I use Joystick 1, *and* 0?

Comment: Maybe this will help ~ from the [docs](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/joystick.html): "The event queue needs to be pumped frequently for some of the methods to work. So call one of pygame.event.get, pygame.event.wait, or pygame.event.pump regularly."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import pygame

pygame.init()
pygame.joystick.init()

# List the available joystick devices
joysticks = [pygame.joystick.Joystick(i) for i in range(pygame.joystick.get_count())]

# Initialize all detected joysticks
for joystick in joysticks:
    joystick.init()
    print(f"Joystick {joystick.get_id()}: {joystick.get_name()}")

times = 0
# Example: Print the position of the left and right analog sticks for all detected joysticks
while True:
    pygame.event.get()
    for joystick in joysticks:
        left_x_axis = joystick.get_axis(0)
        left_y_axis = joystick.get_axis(1)
        right_x_axis = joystick.get_axis(2)
        right_y_axis = joystick.get_axis(3)

        print(f"Left Joystick: X={left_x_axis}, Y={left_y_axis}, Right Joystick: X={right_x_axis}, Y={right_y_axis}")
```

I used a different method that works. Basically instead of asking to see if it exists, I made one variable equal 2 joysticks, making it so that I can split that variable into 2 joysticks.